# Fully Featured C++ Assert Dialog?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assertions

I'm looking for a good, fully featured C++ assert macro for VisualStudio. With features like be able to ignore an assert once or always, to be able to break exactly where the macro gets called (and not inside macro code), and getting a stack trace.

Before I have to hunker down and write one, I figured I'd ask if anyone knows about any available ones out there.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: platform? (filler for >=15 char comment)

Comment: "be able to break exactly where the macro gets called (and not inside macro code)"  Good luck with this one.  If you find a way to do this while still being able to generate line number & filename string, I'd love to see it!  Using macros to do the strings, I was never able to find a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Charles Nicholson's blog](http://cnicholson.net/2009/02/stupid-c-tricks-adventures-in-assert/) for a good discussion of an `assert` macro.  His solution breaks the debugger at the faulting line of code (and not inside the failed assertion handler), and he also solves the problem of not getting warnings about unused variables when assertions are disabled without incurring any runtime costs.

Comment: Works for me! The article is really well written. The code even has a way set your own handler, so that is where I'd add a dialog box with options.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an article I wrote for DDJ that described, among other things, a library that does much of what you're looking for.  Although I don't just use macros, I also implement functions in a DLL.

http://www.ddj.com/architect/184406106

The article from a few years ago and, although I have made many additions, I still use it very liberally in my everyday code.

Answer (score 1):

[_ASSERTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezb1wyez.aspx) breaks exactly where you want it - but does not meet your other criteria.

_ASSERTE is nice because it displays the actual assertion text along with the filename and line number.  This means you can do this:

```
_ASSERTE(bufLen > 0 && "bufLen needs to be greater than 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenOffice has some assertion code](http://www.krugle.org/kse/entfiles/framework/openoffice.org/head/framework/framework/inc/macros/debug/assertion.hxx#2) that has an option of logging to a message box.  Probably not exactly what you want, but instructive maybe?

Comment: Hi John! I realized I didn't specify the platform in my original question. So I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I released [`PPK_ASSERT`](https://github.com/gpakosz/Assert). While it doesn't open a dialog box, on Windows the default handler opens a console where you get to read the assertion message and get to decide which action to take.

```
#include <pempek_assert.h>

int main()
{
  float min = 0.0f;
  float max = 1.0f;
  float v = 2.0f;
  PPK_ASSERT(v > min && v < max, "invalid value: %f, must be between %f and %f", v, min, max);

  return 0;
}
```